# Use AsyncElasticsearch to perform a cross-index query and get a document

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I use an AsyncElasticsearch client instance in order  to retrieve a document from an Elasticsearch database:
`doc = await client.get(index=some_index, id=some_id)`

Documentation  is [here](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/async.html#elasticsearch.AsyncElasticsearch.get)

The above is successful only when I query a specific index.
If I pass a pattern such as `some_index*` then it fails to return a document and instead I get a CORS error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can not use a wildcard (*) when doing a GET by document _id. When requesting a document by _id you must provide the individual index (or alias).

Wildcards and cross-index operations can be used only when performing searches:
*example*: `GET /index-pattern-*/_search`

[See here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/superuser-doesnt-have-access-to-read-a-document/280128/2)